# The Dimension Theorem via Transfinite Recursion

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory

**Dimension Theorem.** Let $K$ be a field and $V$ be a vector space over $K$. Let $\mathscr{B}$ and $\mathscr{C}$ be bases of $V$. Then $|\mathscr{B}|=|\mathscr{C}|$.

For finite-dimensional (a priori, finitely generated) vector spaces, this theorem admits a nice proof that roughly goes as follows: One assumes WLOG that one of the bases has minimal cardinality, which is necessarily finite, and then swaps out vectors from the basis with vectors of the other basis one by one, in a way that each of the intermediate sets is a basis. After finitely many steps, all vectors from the original basis will have been swapped out and since a proper subset of basis can't be a basis, one concludes that we arrived at the other basis, which has hence the same number of elements.

I am trying to adapt this proof to the general case of arbitrary vector spaces by way of transfinite recursion. An incomplete proof attempt goes as follows:

Assume WLOG that $\mathscr{B}$ has minimal cardinality among all bases of $V$ (the class of cardinals is totally ordered under AC, so this makes sense). Index $\mathscr{B}=\{v_i\colon i\in I\}$ and choose a well-ordering $\mathscr{C}=\{w_{\gamma}\colon\gamma<\eta\}$ for some ordinal $\eta$. The goal now is to construct a set $I_{\alpha}\subseteq I$ for each ordinal $\alpha$, such that $I_{\alpha}\subseteq\bigcap_{\gamma<\alpha}I_{\gamma}$ and the associated set $\mathscr{B}_{\alpha}\colon=\{w_{\gamma}\colon\gamma<\alpha\}\cup\{v_i\colon i\in I_{\alpha}\}$ is a basis of $V$ satisfying $|\mathscr{B}_{\alpha}|=|\mathscr{B}|$. Proceed by transfinite recursion:

Defining $I_0=I$, i.e. $\mathscr{B}_0=\mathscr{B}$ does the job for the zero case. For the successor case, assume that $\mathscr{B}_{\alpha}$ and $I_{\alpha}$ have been constructed as desired. Since $\mathscr{B}_{\alpha}$ is a basis, there is a linear combination $w_{\alpha}=\sum_{\gamma<\alpha}a_{\gamma}w_{\gamma}+\sum_{i\in I_{\alpha}}b_iv_i$ with $a_{\gamma},b_i\in K$ for $\gamma<\alpha$ and $i\in I_{\alpha}$ respectively and such that almost all of them are zero. There is a $j\in I_{\alpha}$, such that $b_j\neq0$, otherwise $\mathscr{C}$ would be linearly dependent. This implies that $B\colon=\{w_{\gamma}\colon\gamma<\alpha+1\}\cup\{v_i\colon i\in I_{\alpha}\setminus\{j\}\}=\mathscr{B}_{\alpha}\setminus\{v_j\}\cup\{w_{\alpha}\}$ spans $V$. By a standard Zorn's lemma argument, $B$ contains a basis $\mathscr{B}_{\alpha+1}$ containing $\{w_{\gamma}\colon\gamma<\alpha+1\}$ (as this set is linearly independent). Now, $|\mathscr{B}_{\alpha+1}|\le|B|\le|\mathscr{B}_{\alpha}|=|\mathscr{B}|$, but $|\mathscr{B}|\le|\mathscr{B}_{\alpha+1}|$ by minimality of $\mathscr{B}$, so $|\mathscr{B}_{\alpha+1}|=|\mathscr{B}|$ by Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein. The corresponding index set is $I_{\alpha+1}=\{i\in I_{\alpha}\setminus\{j\}\colon v_i\in\mathscr{B}_{\alpha+1}\}$. (This is essentially the finite-dimensional argument alluded to in the beginning.)

Now assume that $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal and $I_{\gamma}$ and $\mathscr{B}_{\gamma}$ have been defined as desired for all $\gamma<\alpha$. The natural choice is to define $I_{\alpha}\colon=\bigcap_{\gamma<\alpha}I_{\gamma}$, i.e. $\mathscr{B}_{\alpha}=\{w_{\gamma}\colon\gamma<\alpha\}\cup\{v_i\colon i\in\bigcap_{\gamma<\alpha}I_{\gamma}\}$ (this is the "limit" of $\mathscr{B}_{\gamma}$ as "$\gamma\nearrow\alpha$" in the right interpretation). Assume $\{w_{\gamma_1},...,w_{\gamma_n},v_{i_1},...,v_{i_m}\}\subseteq\mathscr{B}_{\alpha}$ with $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\gamma_1,...,\gamma_n<\alpha$, $i_1,...,i_m\in I_{\alpha}$ is linearly dependent. WLOG, assume $\gamma_1<...<\gamma_n$. We have $\gamma_n+1<\alpha$, because $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal and so $i_1,..,i_m\in I_{\gamma_n+1}$, hence $\{w_{\gamma_1},...,w_{\gamma_n},v_{i_1},...,v_{i_m}\}\subseteq\mathscr{B}_{\gamma_n+1}$, contradicting that $\mathscr{B}_{\gamma_n+1}$ is a basis. Thus, $\mathscr{B}_{\alpha}$ is linearly independent.

A way in which to make the earlier statement about limits precise is to note that $\mathscr{B}_{\alpha}=\bigcup_{\zeta<\alpha}\bigcap_{\zeta\le\xi<\alpha}\mathscr{B}_{\xi}=\bigcap_{\zeta<\alpha}\bigcup_{\zeta\le\xi<\alpha}\mathscr{B}_{\xi}$. It would be desirable to derive $|\mathscr{B}_{\alpha}|\le|\mathscr{B}|$ from this, for then if $\mathscr{B}_{\alpha}$ is a basis, we again have $|\mathscr{B}|\le|\mathscr{B}_{\alpha}|$ by minimality and then $|\mathscr{B}_{\alpha}|=|\mathscr{B}|$ by Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein. The best I can manage is to note $|\mathscr{B}_{\alpha}|\le|\bigcup_{\zeta\le\xi<\alpha}\mathscr{B}_{\xi}|$; if $\mathscr{B}$ is infinite (this can be assumed WLOG as the finite case is already taken care off with just the zero and successor case) and there is a $\zeta$ such that $|\{\xi\colon\zeta\le\xi<\alpha\}|\le|\mathscr{B}|$, then this implies the result, but I don't know if such a $\zeta$ always exists and it would be ideal to have no need for differentiating the finite and infinite case. Even worse, I do not know whether $\mathscr{B}_{\alpha}$ is a generating set at all. $I_{\alpha}$ has been made to be as large as possible without violating the monotonicity and $\mathscr{B}_{\alpha}$ is linearly independent, so if anything, it would need to be enlarged to a basis using some $w_{\gamma},\gamma\ge\alpha$, but this feels unnatural and although a Zorn's lemma argument demonstrates this is possible, I wouldn't see a priori how that could be done without potentially enlarging the cardinality.

If these work out, the transfinite recursion goes through and defines a basis $\mathscr{B}_{\alpha}$ for all ordinals $\alpha$. In particular, $\mathscr{C}\subseteq\mathscr{B}_{\eta}$ and, since a proper subset of a basis can't be a basis, $\mathscr{C}=\mathscr{B}_{\eta}$, hence $|\mathscr{C}|=|\mathscr{B}_{\eta}|=|\mathscr{B}|$. Since any basis has the same cardinality as $\mathscr{B}$, all bases then have the same cardinality.

This proof attempt can also be phrased in terms of Zorn's lemma entirely. Let
$$\mathcal{M}\colon=\{(\mathscr{B}^{\prime},\mathscr{C}^{\prime})\colon\mathscr{B}^{\prime}\subseteq\mathscr{B},\mathscr{C}^{\prime}\subseteq\mathscr{C},\mathscr{B}^{\prime}\cup\mathscr{C}^{\prime}\text{ is a basis of $V$},|\mathscr{B}^{\prime}\cup\mathscr{C}^{\prime}|=\mathscr{B}\}.$$
Then $(\mathscr{B},\emptyset)\in\mathcal{M}$, so $\mathcal{M}\neq\emptyset$. Defining $(\mathscr{B}^{\prime},\mathscr{C}^{\prime})\le(\mathscr{B}^{\prime\prime},\mathscr{C}^{\prime\prime})\colon\Leftrightarrow\mathscr{B}^{\prime}\supseteq\mathscr{B}^{\prime\prime}\land\mathscr{C}^{\prime}\subseteq\mathscr{C}^{\prime\prime}$ for $(\mathscr{B}^{\prime},\mathscr{C}^{\prime}),(\mathscr{B}^{\prime\prime},\mathscr{C}^{\prime\prime})\in\mathcal{M}$ yields a partial order on $\mathcal{M}$. There is one sensible set-theoretic choice for the upper bound of a chain in $\mathcal{M}$ and proving it lies in $\mathcal{M}$ again is analogous to the limit case in the above transfinite recursion. If that is true, Zorn's lemma implies the existence of a maximal element and a swapping argument similar to the successor case in the above transfinite recursion shows that the maximal element must be $(\emptyset,\mathcal{C})$, so in particular $|\mathscr{C}|=|\emptyset\cup\mathscr{C}|=|\mathscr{B}|$. The transfinite recursion approach feels more natural to me, but completing either proof should directly give insight into how to complete the other proof.

So my questions are: Is the $\mathscr{B}_{\alpha}$ constructed in the limit case a basis? Does it have the same cardinality as $\mathscr{B}$? If yes, how can it be proven? If no, is there a way to salvage the proof attempt?

Answer (score 0):

The equality of sizes for infinite bases can be shown from:

> If $X$ is an infinite set, then $[X]^{<\omega}$, the set of all finite subsets of $X$, has the same cardinality as $X$.

Write elements from one base as linear combinations from the other base and note the finitely many base elements used..

Comment: I'm aware of the standard proof, but my question is about a specific, different method of proof and whether that can be made to work.

Comment: @Thorgott I'm not sure of the switching idea will work. But why come up with a more complicated proof anyway?